# Presenter saves the textbox value in gwtp, gwt

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I tried to develop a shopping cart application.

I am able to process the deal. but when the user click the fresh start after completing the deal the first page starts with the value which I have entered previously.

I am using gwtp, uibinders, I have back, cancel, next functionality in series of screens.

what to do to make sure the screen is blank for every new start of deal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which design pattern you use, but usually a "view" keeps its state after it is hidden. When you show your view the second time, you have to reset the values of all fields (textboxes, inputs, etc.), or they will show their state from the previous time.

Comment: Do you want me to clear all the information in onReset() in presenter class.

Comment: I can't tell without looking at your code. Before you show the view, you have to reset all values - the same way you set them when you show the view for the first time.

Comment: My consideration is, I have to show the values when they click back button in application or in browser. So, simply calling reset might reset its values irrespective of navigation. So how to handle this?

Comment: Only reset values after you processed the transaction, not when a user navigates to the view.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need to. But how to notify the all the view that the transaction has been completed. do you want me to have a Boolean value and check for it. I need suggestion in this.

Comment: You don't need a boolean. You do it in the callback from your transaction.

Comment: I have series of screens, last screen completes the transaction. how will I get this info to other screens?